# before, when and past-perfect

Tags: past-perfect

1. I waited for an hour before he appeared
2. I had waited for an hour before he appeared
3. I had waited for an hour when he appeared

These all are correct ? Further, these all share same meaning ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they all mean the same thing, but when you use " before" in the sentence the use of the past perfect is optional, because the word "before" makes it clear what happened first. This is not the case when "when" is used. 
It is also possible to use the past perfect progressive in sentences 2 and 3: " I had been waiting...".

Comment: *because the word "before" makes it clear what happened first* - How does it make the usage of **Past Perfect** optional then? To me, using *for an hour* and *before*, emphasizes that **I** had completed waiting before he appeared.

Comment: "For an hour" in combination with past perfect to me doesn't mean completion, but duration.

Comment: But "...for an hour before..." implies both completion and duration because afterwards "he appeared".

Comment: From Collins dictionary (https://grammar.collinsdictionary.com/easy-learning/the-past-perfect-tense) - *an action or state that began before another action in the past and continued up to the time of the second action and perhaps even beyond that time.* **Ashraf had already known my brother for two years when I met him.**

Comment: Yes, but "to know" is a stative verb. Stative verbs are not used in a continuous tense.

Comment: Do you imply that otherwise "to know" would be in **Past Continuous**? My point is that in the original sentence, an action of "waiting" is independent from "he appeared" and so **Past Simple** can be used for it.