# We had been / were waiting for an hour

Tags: past-tense, past-continuous, past-vs-past-perfect

We were waiting **for an hour**. 
We had been waiting **for an hour** when she finally came. 
we were waiting **for an hour** when she finally came.

what's the difference in these sentences?

Comment: Semantically, the only difference is the extra information in the ***when-*** clause of the second and third examples. Idiomatically, Past Perfect (#2) is more likely with ***waiting for an hour***, but Simple Past would be more likely with a different verb element, such as *We were **sitting in the garden** when she arrived*. Perhaps someone else will explain ***why*** the default tense choice changes there. Probably to do with the fact that perforce the waiting ends when she arrives, but the sitting *could* continue.

Comment: @FumbleFingers What I meant to understand is that when to use “we were waiting for an hour” and “we had been waiting for an hour”, that’s why I asked the difference.

Comment: The first two are correct, the third isn't.

Comment: The last example is strange because of the use of "when" and a period of time spent waiting.  It's as if you are saying she arrived during the time period you were waiting, which is odd. It's not clear that the waiting finished when she arrived. Were you waiting for her, or did she interrupt the wait for something else, and then the waiting conitnued? I would avoid this construction.

Comment: @KateBunting when to use first and second, what's the difference?

Comment: @BillyKerr could you tell me the above question?

Comment: @Kate Bunting: I certainly think it's "unlikely", but "incorrect" seems a bit extreme for version #3. We'd immediately accept, say, *We were **resting** for an hour when she arrived* (implying that we'd decided to ***rest*** for an hour, and she arrived while we were resting). We could have decided to ***wait*** for an hour (***for*** her to arrive, ***or*** for some other reason), and she arrived *during that waiting period*. From that perspective, it's effectively a matter of semantics rather than syntax.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [before, when and past-perfect](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/236893/before-when-and-past-perfect)

Comment: ...also [had been working vs was working](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/335541/had-been-working-vs-was-working) and [Is the past perfect continuous really necessary?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/267290/is-the-past-perfect-continuous-really-necessary), among others.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I saw this example **We waited (or were waiting) for an hour.** in *Grammar in use*, so I want to know if we can use *' we did something for + duration'* and *' we were doing something for + duration'* ***interchangeably***. 
I think the difference is just the emphasis on the ongoing action and completed action in the past.

Comment: Without more context, I don't think it's meaningful to attempt to distinguish *We waited for an hour* from *We were waiting for an hour.*

Comment: The difference is that _we had been waiting for an hour_ indicates that the event (her coming) marked the _end_ of that hour - see James's answer. (I accept @FumbleFingers' comment that No. 3 could be acceptable in certain circumstances.)

Comment: @KateBunting I think we'd use the second instead of the third sentence because the waiting started in the earlier past and continued up to the interruption (when she finally came). And in this case, we should use the second one.

Answer (score 0):

- **The first sentence** is more general and lacks a connection to another
  event.
- **The second sentence** emphasizes the duration of the waiting and its
  completion before a specific event, adding a sense of anticipation
  and relief when the event occurs.
- **The third sentence focuses** on the action of waiting as it was
  happening up until the event occurred, without the same emphasis on
  the duration's completion before the event.

Each sentence tells us a similar story with slight shifts in focus, whether it's the simple fact of waiting, the buildup to her arrival, or the timing of the events.

**Hope this helps hwkal :)**

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure we can justify the third sentence.

Comment: @AndyBonner: Suppose the context is that "we" have one of those cars whose anti-theft alarm has been activated. We've tried to follow the instructions in the owner's handbook for turning off the alarm, but we keep getting it wrong, and each time we get it wrong, the enforced delay before we can try again doubles. Over the years, I've had this problem several times with Vauxalls (because the process is complicated, not because I'm an idiot! :) Further suppose that "she" is a grease-monkey or locksmith, and we only called her out when the "doubled up wait time" reached 64 minutes!